# Is there away to pull a users standard layout in edit mode and place it on a VF page?

Tags: javascript, controller, standardcontroller

I know there's a ways to do this using  tag to view the detail page, but once you hit edit it will use salesforce standard edit page. I've also created a custom edit page but the problem I'm running into is not all custom fields a user created will show up on the edit page. It would be awesome if I can generate my custom visual force page to look like what the users custom layout already is.

Comment: Are you just trying to pull in the page layout into a custom Visualforce page for editing a record?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Is this even possible? The reason I want to do this is because I have a custom page error message with HTML. In spring '13, salesforce made there pagemessage to escape html on there standard edit page. Although they did patch this up but wanted to see if what im trying to do can be done.

Comment: Maybe you could make just a section of the page layout the error message rather than the entire page (i.e., write the Visualforce just for the error message rather than the whole page)? That would be my suggestion, find a way to get it to work with the page layout before moving the entire page to custom code just to display an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Nope :-( let's all vote on the idea!

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrQtAAK