# Can I send a user to a standard layout edit page at the end of a wizard?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, case, controller-extension

I want to do something that's been [asked about before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7684/is-there-away-to-pull-a-users-standard-layout-in-edit-mode-and-place-it-on-a-vf), but I am going to give some more reasoning in case I'm missing a better solution.

I am developing a package.  As part of this package, there's a custom wizard for creating the case and some related fields.  The steps I'd use are:

1. Log call and caller (and dedupe)
2. Take notes and determine basic case information
3. Fill out details about case

I would love to be able to use the case's record type to generate the final page of the wizard.  In an ideal world, administrators who install this package would be able to control the layout for each record type and thereby control the final page of the wizard.

Maybe the best way to do this is simply to set the record type in step 2, save all the information, and send the user to the edit page of the Case at the end of the wizard.  Does that work?  What am I missing here?

Comment: A wizard would normally only persist changes when the last page is saved; you are suggesting saving on the penultimate page and then showing the standard edit page. But if you label the button that does that "Save & Edit" perhaps it is reasonable.

Comment: @KeithC That's a great point re user expectations and SF standards.  What does that final redirect look like in Apex?  `return ApexPages.StandardController(case).edit();`?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman yep, that's what you're looking for

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Moved the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wizard would normally only persist changes when the last page is saved; you are suggesting saving on the penultimate page and then showing the standard edit page. But if you label the button that does that "Save & Edit" perhaps it is reasonable.